# Tensorflow: Different dropout probabilities for timeseries values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a LSTM model in Tensorflow and want to apply dropout before the recurrent model part.

Imagine a timeseries of 5 values t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 as input and I want to apply dropout with probabilities p1,p2,p3,p4,p5.

Comment: You want to apply dropout with different probabilities per time-step? Why? You'd probably need to write your own LSTM cell, not terribly hard if you know how to code an LSTM (colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs), though figuring out that dropout scheme sounds complicated. You'll also need to master the `tf.while` loop (TF control flow), again, not hard if you know how, just another thing with a bit of a learning curve. And that all seems like a lot of effort for a rather uncommon design choice, hence the question: why?

Comment: Thanks. The idea is to implement it before the LSTM cell to focus learning on recent timesteps rather than earlier ones. I'm not sure if it makes too much sense but I'd like to try it out.

Comment: Dropout changes the configuration of the weights, there's no way to affect the weights of the LSTM cell (there are 4 sets of weights) without implementing dropout within the LSTM cell, which is supported as a parameter to the LSTM cell - but not in the way you've described.

Comment: See it as following: I have INPUT --> LSTM CELL --> OUTPUT. The input is fed in batches. Now I want to randomly set some of these input values to 0 during training based on a predefined probability for each input. This should happen before the whole LSTM CELL.

Comment: Perhaps, here's another related question that might be worth reviewing, not sure if it's directly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458902/does-applying-a-dropout-layer-after-the-embedding-layer-have-the-same-effect-as/49459319#49459319

Comment: Thanks David, that answer is quite related. But still, how could I set the dropout rate to be different for each input node, e. g.
dropout_prob = [0.9, 0.89, 0.88, 0.85, ... until equal to length of input]

Comment: That's why these are comments and not answers. :)  I don't think there's an easy answer there. I think you're going to have to write the RNN from scratch to achieve that feature. Or perhaps take an existing RNN cell and modify it to suit your needs. In either case not a trival task.